# Lua: gsub: can't process captured numeric string as a number

Tags: lua, typeerror, gsub, substitution

I've spent hours on this one, and I'm still stuck. And the really baffling thing is, according to the Lua documentation, I shouldn't even be having this problem:

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.2.1

I've got the following Lua script:

```
local takevol = tn(chunk:match("VOLPAN%s%d%s%d%s([+-]?%d*%.?%d*)"))
newchunk = string.gsub(chunk,"(\n%s*PT%s%d%s)([+-]?%d*%.?%d*)","%1"..takevol*tonumber("%2"))
```

The source I am working with is an item data chunk (string format) that looks like this (truncated for brevity):

```
VOLPAN 1 0 15.848932 -1
SOFFS 365.84808854166607
PLAYRATE 0.25 0 0 -1 0 0.0025
CHANMODE 3
GUID {79C49752-9C32-D545-A54E-8CFFF9ACC14E}
<VOLENV
EGUID {92E4F259-A31C-0E49-81CB-B2C1ABA21CD4}
ACT 1 -1
VIS 1 1 1
LANEHEIGHT 0 0
ARM 0
DEFSHAPE 0 -1 -1
VOLTYPE 1
PT 0 1 0
>
>
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the volume value from the line starting `VOLPAN` (15.848932), multiply that with each second number captured from the lines starting `PT`, replacing the second number value in each `PT` line with the result, which, for this example, would come out like this:

```
VOLPAN 1 0 15.848932 -1
SOFFS 365.84808854166607
PLAYRATE 0.25 0 0 -1 0 0.0025
CHANMODE 3
GUID {79C49752-9C32-D545-A54E-8CFFF9ACC14E}
<VOLENV
EGUID {92E4F259-A31C-0E49-81CB-B2C1ABA21CD4}
ACT 1 -1
VIS 1 1 1
LANEHEIGHT 0 0
ARM 0
DEFSHAPE 0 -1 -1
VOLTYPE 1
PT 0 15.848932 0
>
```

In this example, there is just one `PT` line. For some item chunks, there are dozens, which is why I chose gsub to iterate through them. And ultimately, I'll be processing anywhere from a few dozen to ***thousands*** of these items at a time.

Please help me. I'm really at a total loss on how to get the captured value from the `PT` lines into a number format that I can do the multiplication with. I've looked through Lua documentation, read through several semi-related forum posts/questions, and I've experimented with different ways of escaping the variable for the capture, trying to use a function and do the math outside of the gsub command, and a number of other things. But I still just keep getting errors, typically either "attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value" or "attempt to perform arithmetic on a string value".

And, of course, based on the following excerpt from the manual (as linked above), it seems like performing arithmetic on a string value should normally work just fine in Lua.

> Lua provides automatic conversion between string and number values at
> run time. Any arithmetic operation applied to a string tries to
> convert this string to a number, following the usual conversion
> rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need use a function.

> If repl is a function, then this function is called every time a match occurs, with all captured substrings passed as arguments, in order; if the pattern specifies no captures, then the whole match is passed as a sole argument.

```
newchunk = string.gsub(chunk,"(\n%s*PT%s%d%s)([+-]?%d*%.?%d*)",
function (a, b)
    return a..takevol*tonumber(b)
end)
```

You can also merge into one

```
newchunk = string.gsub(chunk, "(VOLPAN%s%d%s%d%s)([+-]?%d*%.?%d*)(.*PT%s%d%s)([+-]?%d*%.?%d*)",
function (a, takevol, c, PTval)
    return a..takevol..c..(takevol*PTval)
end)
```

Comment: Aha! I see. I tried adding a function call for the 3rd arg, but didn't have it encapsulated within the 3rd arg in the gsub function like this. And depending on how I tried passing the captured string to the external function, I would either get a nil value, or "%1", And neither one was allowing me to perform arithmetic on it. So I guess there isn't a way to pass captured values out of gsub. Good to know. Thank you!

Comment: I was just testing this with some items that have multiple points (the `PTval` line). It works for the first one, but doesn't iterate through the others for the replacement. Is still still possible with the two commands merged together? EDIT: Actually, this could be due to a change I may need to make in the pattern matching. Looking into it now.

Comment: It's not possible, you need 2 steps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @shingo for the answer!

I just wanted to share the following code test I just made here as well to illustrate the difference in behavior based on the syntax of how a function is called for the replacement arg in gsub.

Hopefully, this might help anyone else who finds this thread, and happened to be making the same mistakes I was.

First, the correct way to do the function call for replacement string: the string replacement function *enclosed* within the arguments to the gsub command's replacement argument - not external. Optionally, as shown below, the gsub command can also be within a parent function (`modifyCaptures`, in this example) to make it easier to reuse with multiple string replacements.

```
str = "foo 15.687"
print("EXAMPLE 1")
function modifyCaptures (s)
    s = string.gsub(s, "(%d*%.%d*)",function (n)
        print(n)
        return n*10 -- works!
        end)
    return s
end
    
print(modifyCaptures(str.."\n"))
```

Wrong way #1: trying to send the captured string out of gsub using the capture number reference `"%1"`.

```
print("EXAMPLE 2")
function example2(a)
    -- any arithmetic attempt w/ the quoted captured value reference passed as arg here causes error
    print(a)
    return a
end
str = string.gsub(str,'(%d*%.%d*)', example2("%1"))

print(str.."\n")
```

Wrong way #2: trying to either add no argument, or using a generic variable pointer (as is shown in example 1), will only result in `nil` being sent to the external function.

```
print("EXAMPLE 3")
function example3(n)
    --   same as #2, arithmetic causes error
    print(n)
    print(type(n))
    print(tonumber(n))
    print(tostring(n))
    return tostring(n)
end
str = string.gsub(str,"(%d*%.%d*)",example3(n))
print(str..'\n')
```

This is the output from all 3 of the examples above for comparison.

```
--[[
OUTPUT:
EXAMPLE 1 
15.687
foo 156.87

EXAMPLE 2 
%1
foo 15.687

EXAMPLE 3 
nil
nil
nil
nil
foo nil
]]
```